# Python program to find the 3rd position of occurrence of a given string in another given string

Tags: python, string, find, substring, position

how to find Python program to find the 3rd position of  occurrence of a given string in another given string.

```
find_string("I am the the champion of the champions of the champions", "the")
```

Comment: Use `re.finditer()` to get a sequence of `re.Match` objects. Then get the `start` position from the third element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like this to find your '`needle`' in a '`haystack`'

```
import re
haystack = "I am the the champion of the champions of the champions"
needle = "the"


    # print all matches
for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(needle, haystack)):
    print(f"{i+1}, start:{match.start()}, end:{match.end()}")

# or select the third from a list
matches = list(re.finditer(needle, haystack))  # list of all matches
matches[2].start()  # get start position of third match
matches[2].end()  # get end position of third match
```

EDIT:
Using only str.find

```
def find_nth(haystack, needle, n):
    start, lneedle = haystack.find(needle), len(needle)
    for _ in range(n-1):
        start = haystack.find(needle, start + lneedle)
    return start

find_nth(haystack, needle, 3)
```

Comment: i have tried for position of the second occurrence of a given string in another given string

Comment: def find_string(txt, str1):
 return txt.find(str1, txt.find(str1)+1)

Comment: is there a simple way

Comment: I've edited my answer to show an example using only str.find

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
def find_string(txt, str1, n):
    index = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        index = txt.find(str1, index + 1)
    return txt.find(str1, index)
```

Output:

```
find_string("I am the the champion of the champions of the champions", "the", 3)
# Output
# 42
```